# JMeter http sampler spending time in ssl.AppInputStream.read() method

Tags: ssl, jmeter

We are using JMeter to run performance tests. The scripts consists of http samples which are used as requests that are being sent to the server. Then we also have JSR samplers which are only used to generate Auth token using Groovy scripts.

What we are observing is with time, throughput slowly goes down. We hooked up VisualVM and realized that some of the threads are always running. We then did CPU sampling and analyzed the trace of the threads running for a longer duration. What we have observed is the threads that are running for long duration (sometimes forever) are spending time in sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read() method. Note that only a handful of threads are running forever, but when they run, they all are spending time in above method. I think this is somehow impacting the overall throughput. Attaching the trace here for more information.

[image]

Can someone help me understand what this is and why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you share your plan ?

Comment: Yes it hit us too, https://ibb.co/fxcjq29, Debian 10, openjdk-11, jmeter 5.1.1 r1855137, test plan with 300 threads. SSL endpoint. No other clue for the time being